# Not able to bulk download MODIS images

Tags: r, modis, download

I am trying to download Modis NDVI and EVI images. I have used the following R-code:

```
    setwd("/home/karthik/Valmiki/Modis_bands/")
    library(raster)
    library(RCurl)
    source("ModisDownload.R") ##ModisDownload.R is in the setwd directory#
    X="MOD13Q1"
    getMODIS(x=X, h=25, v=6, dates = c('2000.02.18', '2014.07.31'),  version='005')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
    cannot open compressed file 'ModisLP.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Please let me know  me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Where does `ModisDownload.r` come from? Have you tried the r-package `MODIS`?

Comment: I have downloaded ModisDownload.R file from http://r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload. I will check out MODIS package in R.

Comment: I deleted ModisDownload.R and ModisLP.RData in my working directory and downloaded it again from  r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload. This time it worked. Thanks for response.

Comment: I tested the procedure in Debian and it works well too. +1.

Comment: I could not download images with R because the USGS server is using http and ftp ModisDownload.R is, can you help me ??

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95862)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick workaround using the **MODIS** package:

```
# install.packages("MODIS")
library(MODIS)

MODISoptions(localArcPath = "/path/to/modis/files", 
             outDirPath = "/path/to/modis/files/processed")

runGdal("MOD13Q1", collection = "006", # see getCollection("MOD13Q1", forceCheck = TRUE)
        tileH = 25, tileV = 6, # MODIS tile id
        begin = "2000.02.18", end = "2000.03.31", # time period
        SDSstring = "110000000000") # SDS layers to extract (here: NDVI, EVI)
```

If you don't want to extract certain SDS layers, but deal with the raw .hdf files instead, simply use `getHdf` instead of `runGdal` and drop 'SDSstring'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using alternative software to download those images? For example, MODIS data can be accessed via [LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer).  All you need to do is locate an area of your interest and select MODIS imagery in the filter section. Once done you will have the option to download the data on the right.

An example of such imagery can be seen [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo48W.jpg) or view this location on the platform directly [HERE](https://eos.com/landviewer/?lat=45.38495&lng=8.78357&z=8&preset=passiveLowSensors&side=R&slider-id=LV-TUNE-NDNB-NC5B-MjAx-OTA5-MS5o-MTh2-MDQu-MDA2-LjIw-MTkx-MDAw-MzM5-NTM%3D&slider-b=NIR,Red&slider-expression=(B02-B01)%2F(B02%2BB01)&slider-anti&id=LV-TUNE-NDNB-NC5B-MjAx-OTA5-MS5o-MTh2-MDQu-MDA2-LjIw-MTkx-MDAw-MzM5-NTM%3D&b=Red,Green,Blue&cb=true&anti).

Here’s a brief guide to **free** satellite data that can be found on [LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer):

- Landsat 4 - archive 1982-1993
- Landsat 5 - archive 1984-2013
- Landsat 7 - archive since 1999
- **MODIS** - archive since 2012
- Landsat 8 - archive since 2013
- Sentinel-1 - archive since 2014
- Sentinel-2 - archive since 2015